# two node disjoint paths in a tree , such that the multiplication of those lengths get maximum

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I want to find two paths in a tree with n nodes , so that this two paths don't have any common node and the multiplication of lengths of this two paths gets maximum . 
any one can help me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Why the multiplication of lengths?

Comment: if there is two paths with lengths L and M in this tree , the L*M should be maximum ! it's a practice problem and doesn't have any special reason for this :D

Comment: What are the constraints on the edge lengths?  Do all edges have length 1?  Or can they be positive lengths?  Can they be non-integer?

Comment: all edges have length 1 .

Answer (score 2):

First, generate a list of every possible unique path using a recursive procedure.

You end up with m possible paths.

Second, setup an array of m x m elements.

Check every one of the m paths with all the other m-1 paths and store into the array the multiplication of the respective length. Doing so check if the two path have nodes in common. If so store 0.

Third, check the m x m array for the element with the biggest value.

What else could you do? It's very brute-force but if no more informations is known about the tree properties this is the only way.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer :) . this tree include at most 1000 nodes and doesn't have any more information , but this program should be run under 2 second ! so may be brute force doesn't work efficiently !

Comment: If this is a practice problem (as you say in your comments below the posting), then what is the reason for the 2 second runtime?  If you want ANY feasible solution, then a greedy algorithm modification to the above will work.  However, if you want THE (unique?) MAXIMUM solution, well -- then somehow you need all possible combinations.  And there is no theoretical way to obtain those without actually searching for each possibility and evaluating to get whether each one is feasible and its "cost" (L*M).

Comment: quote: "but this program should be run under 2 second". Both the three steps are suitable to be written to run in separate threads. If you write the program in a compiled language (I'd suggest plain C) and it's multithreaded it may do the task in less than 2 secs. If not... add cores. But again... is this just an IT enigma, or does this tree actually come out from some real scenario? I guess some assumptions can be made given the origin of the data. And this could end in a more complex but more efficient algorithm.

Comment: no ! it's just an algorithm enigma . it's a simple tree with at most 1000 nodes . we should write an efficient code to run under 2 seconds . if we progressively prune the tree from one of the  deepest leaves then we have 2 disjoint trees and now we compute longest path in these two tree . again we prune the original tree more and again compute longest paths in these two trees and so on ... but I'm not certain about this approach !

Comment: aha! I know it's not an answer but, as it's academic matter it's likely you may find the answer in some academic articles on the web, like this http://keisan-genkai.lab2.kuis.kyoto-u.ac.jp/reports/2004/nhc/Ryuhei-Uehara-NHC2005.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts. If there are two values a and b that add up to n, the maximum value of a*b is when a == b (for simplicity assume that n is even).
If there is a path going through all n nodes cut it into two nearly equal parts. For such graphs for even n the answer will be (n^2) / 4 and for odd n it will be (n-1)/2 * (n+1)/2 = (n^2 - 1) / 4.
If there is no path going through all n nodes you will have to use some other techniques. But The upper bounds are as above.

Comment: I think in a tree there is no path going through all n nodes !

Comment: Some severely unbalanced trees have paths with n nodes.

Comment: yeah :) but not all of trees ! so it can't be a complete answer for this problem

Comment: Can you provide more details on the tree used ? In a balanced rooted binary tree with n nodes each pair of nodes has an LCA that is at most height lg(n) away (log to base 2). In that case there is an upper limit on the maximum length of paths (2 * lg(n)). The second largest disjoint node will have size (2*lg(n) - 2). The product hence will be roughly 4*lg(n)*(lg(n) - 1). I can't come up with a rigorous proof right now but I assume that for rooted trees you will have an approximate of this one. You can probably prune the number of paths that you check.

Comment: Actually strike the calculation. The second largest will not be 2 * lg(n) - 2 but rather close to lg(n). Again it feels like one can get a good technique if more knowledge about the tree is provided.